# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

Tags: ssl, https, dns

I have problem with testing my in app purchases. When I try to buy some points, In my console it appear this NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

I tried to add this code to info.plist but it doesnt work

NSAppTransportSecurity

NSAllowsArbitraryLoads

In below is link to screenshot with this issue, when I click to buy some coins, it still show  "wait!"

http://postimg.org/image/j7hpxwjhh/

Have you some solution for this problem?

thank you for quick response

Comment: i am having same problem 
did you find the solution???